# Ignite semaphore stucks on release()

Tags: ignite

I have started 3 server and 2 client nodes of ignite. If I stop one server node both client stuck on semaphore release call.

Could you please tell me the reason?

```
 java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.9/Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.9/LockSupport.java:323)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:178)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:141)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get(GridCacheAdapter.java:4851)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.repairableGet(GridCacheAdapter.java:4810)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get(GridCacheAdapter.java:1469)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProxyImpl.get(GridCacheProxyImpl.java:400)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheSemaphoreImpl$Sync$1.call(GridCacheSemaphoreImpl.java:277)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheSemaphoreImpl$Sync$1.call(GridCacheSemaphoreImpl.java:271)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.retryTopologySafe(GridCacheUtils.java:1423)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheSemaphoreImpl$Sync.compareAndSetGlobalState(GridCacheSemaphoreImpl.java:271)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheSemaphoreImpl$Sync.tryReleaseShared(GridCacheSemaphoreImpl.java:238)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.releaseShared(java.base@11.0.9/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1382)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheSemaphoreImpl.release(GridCacheSemaphoreImpl.java:790)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheSemaphoreImpl.release(GridCacheSemaphoreImpl.java:778)
```

Comment: Please provide stack trace of stuck threads.

Comment: @alamar Added stack trace

Comment: Can you please prepare a reproducer project and e-mail it to Apache Ignite userlist? Then somebody will check.

Comment: our application is too big. I will be difficult to implement in separate project. But i will try